# Change reply-to header of admin new order email woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am struggling from a long time to change reply-to header for admin new order email. I want that when a new order is placed, the email which admin receives have reply-to header as customer email. Right now it is set as admin email. Whenever admin click reply for reply, that email will be sent to customer.

I tried to change From Address in woocommerce email settings but it effects on customer email header too.

Kindly suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can do this with a filter. Your theme should have a functions.php file -- try adding the below to the top of that file somewhere:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_reply_to_wc_admin_new_order', 10, 3 );

function add_reply_to_wc_admin_new_order( $headers = '', $id = '', $order ) {
    if ( $id == 'new_order' ) {
        $reply_to_email = $order->billing_email;
        $headers .= "Reply-to: <$reply_to_email>\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can i get customer email here instead of some static email?

Comment: Yep! I've changed my answer to let you use the order's email address

Comment: Hi, i tried your code, but that's not working. I cann't see reply-to header in email and when click on reply button it shows my email id which i set in Settings > General for Email Address field.

Comment: It woks for me.. Thanks :)

Comment: This feature has been implemented into WooCommerce and now it's no more necessary to change the reply-to header.